# Weibel's H-book, Milnor's exact sequence for spectral sequence of filtered complex, Theorem 5.5.5

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences, limits-and-colimits

This is a question which I asked on StackExchange first, but might be more suited here.

I got stuck on the proof of Theorem 5.5.5 in Weibel's book. Not only that, but I also could not even find the statement of said theorem in any other source, so I am completely at a loss how to proceed.

The result is called the Eilenberg-Moore Filtration Sequence for complete complexes. Interestingly, I was unable to find this result under this name anywhere else.

> Suppose the filtered chain complex $C$ is complete with respect to it's filtration $F_*C$, i.e $C=\lim\limits_{\leftarrow} C/F_pC.$ In this case the exact sequence $$0\longrightarrow\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}}^1H_{n+1}(C/F_pC)\longrightarrow H_n(C)\longrightarrow\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}} H_n(C/F_pC)\longrightarrow0$$
> takes the form
> $$0\longrightarrow\bigcap F_pH_n(C)\longrightarrow H_n(C)\longrightarrow H_n(C)/\bigcap F_pH_n(C)\longrightarrow0$$
> and $${\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}} H_n(C/F_pC)\cong {\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}} H_n(C)/F_pH_n(C). $$

The first exact sequence is Milnor's $\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}}^1$ exact sequence (Theorem 3.5.8):

> Let $C_i$ be a tower of chain complexes satisfying the Mittag-Leffler condition, and set $C=\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}} C_i$. Then there is an exact sequence for each n:
> $$0\longrightarrow\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}}^1H_{n+1}(C_i)\longrightarrow H_n(C)\longrightarrow\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}} H_n(C_i)\longrightarrow0$$

The proof then proceeds as follows:

> Taking the limit of the exact sequence of towers
> $$0\longrightarrow F_pH_*(C)\longrightarrow H_*(C)\longrightarrow H_*(C)/F_pH_*(C)\longrightarrow0$$
> we find that there is a monomorphism $H_*(C)/\bigcap F_pH_*(C)\to {\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}} H_*(C)/F_pH_*(C)$. Also, there is an exact sequnce
> $$0\longrightarrow H_*(C)/F_pH_*(C)\to H_*(C/F_pC),$$
> which also gives a monomorphism ${\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}} H_*(C)/F_pH_*(C)\to \lim\limits_{\longleftarrow} H_*(C/F_pC)$. This combines into a monomorphism $H_*(C)/\bigcap F_pH_*(C)\to\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow} H_*(C/F_pC)$.

Then Weibel says to "combine this with the $\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}}^1$ sequence of 3.5.8". And I don't get this last step at all. It seems we have not yet connected $\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}}^1$ and $\bigcap F_pH_n(C)$.

This result is used quite a bit in later sections, so I would really like to understand it. I would be thankful for any help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have constructed, up to this point, a monomorphism $H_n C / \bigcap F_p H_n C \to \lim H_n(C/F_p C)$, and this is compatible with the map from $H_n C$. This allows you to construct the right-hand square, and then assemble all of, the following map of exact sequences:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0
@>>>
\bigcap F_pH_n(C)
@>>>
H_n(C)
@>>> H_n(C)/\bigcap F_pH_n(C)
@>>>
0\\
@.
@VVV
@|
@VVV
@.\\
0
@>>>
\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}}^1H_{n+1}(C/F_pC)
@>>>
H_n(C)
@>>>
\mathbin{\lim\limits_{\longleftarrow}} H_n(C/F_pC)
@>>>0.
\end{CD}$$

The middle map is an isomorphism and you have shown that right-hand vertical map is injective. Applying the snake lemma, we find that all the vertical maps are isomorphisms.